# Get missing element from an array. In case the element is not missing return null

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Hi I started with JS and wanted to get missing element from an array. In case there is no element missing I want to get null. However I can either get null or the element I want. Both not working at the same time. Could you help ? Thank you in advance

```js
function getMissingElement(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (Math.abs(array[i + 1] - array[i] != 1)) {
      return (array[i + 1] - 1);
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }
}

getMissingElement([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);
getMissingElement([6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
```

Comment: What do you mean by a `missing element`?

Comment: @WillardSolutions Apparently a missing number in a sequential sequence.

Comment: The numbers in array e.g. getMissingElement([6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15]) increase by 1 but 9 is missing, so the function should return 9. In the next case getMissingElement([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]); nothing is missing so it should return null.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you are trying to do (what do you mean by missing element)
But notice 2 things:

1. As you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs), `Math.abs()` expects a number as an input, and you seem to pass in a boolean.
2. In Javascript, you should use `!==` instead of `!=` to check for an inequality

Comment: if you know both operands are numbers, `!=` is perfectly fine.

Comment: #1 is just a typo, the `)` is in the wrong place.

Comment: @Barmar you're right :)

Comment: ok, once again guys. In this array getMissingElement([6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]) there is a squence from 6-15 increased by 1 but 9 is missing, so i should get it. In the second array there is also a sequence 1-7 getMissingElement([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);, so nothing missing and I should get null. Regarding Math.abs() I know that it expects a number and it is getting the number.